# KeyCloak composite role not added to access_token

Tags: keycloak, access-token

Could not understand why my composite role not added to access_token. I created a simple role (named Child) and assigned it to a user. Then I created a composite role (named Parent) and linked with Child role. I suppose that composite role will be added to access token, but this didn't happen.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, do you still have any doubts ?

Answer (score 0):

A user to whom is granted a composite role will inherent all roles **within** the composite role. Notice the word "within".

So if the role "Child" was composed by the role "Parent" (Child -> Parent) and you assign the role "Child" to a user then that user will also get the role "Parent" assign to it. However, if you had just assigned the role "Parent" to the user, then that user would only get the role "Parent".

This is what is happening in your use-case, you have the role "Parent" that is composed by the role "Child" (Parent -> Child) if you assign the role "Child" to the user you will not see the "Parent" there. However, if you assign the role Parent to the user, you will see both the "Parent" and "Child" roles assigned to that user.